# Башня || Олимпиада ACM-ICPC

Tags: c++, алгоритм, математика, геометрия, олимпиада

Есть вопрос к задаче по алгоритмическому программированию:

> У нас дано высоту башни и радиус земли, которую можно считать
>   идеальной сферой. Нужно найти площадь видимой поверхности земли (при
>   том что высотой наблюдателя можно пренебречь). Например: R = 6371, H
>   = 1. Ответ: 40023.891393 (погрешность в пределах 10<sup>-4</sup>)

Мы пришли к выводу, что такие варианты решения (формулы) или является не корректными или не полными:

```
— S = 2*Pi*R*H; Площадь сферического сегмента.
— S = 2*Pi*R(R + r/2 - sqrt(R^2 + r^2)); Площадь поверхности 
                                         шарового сектора.
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ну, вообще-то, если не ошибся в математике, то

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Элементарная геометрия уровня нынешнего... ну не позже 10 класса:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Воу, спасибо, еще такой вопросик, и так очень вам благодарен, откуда эта формула, мы весь интернет обыскали, ничего даже такого я не замечал)

Comment: оттуда, что касательные с радиусом образуют прямоугольные треугольники

Comment: Не обижайтесь, но страшная беда нынешнего поколения - сводить знания к поиску в Интернете... Недаром я всегда говорю, что так стар, что помню те времена, когда программисты знали математику :) Формулы-то **элементарнейшие**!

Comment: @Harry как будто сейчас все не знают) Или мне уже в старики тоже записываться...

Comment: Я все понимаю, действительно, знания математики у меня плохое, будем учить, развитие - вот к чему я сейчас стремлюсь, главная моя ошибка - это не желание учить основы математики, после чего уже даже с желанием не мог выучить, извините за глупый вопрос.

Comment: @pavel Давно пора :) У меня малой в физматшколе учится, и там ну крайне жесткое деление между собой на физиков, математиков и информатиков. Мне приходится прилагать еще те усилия, заставляя заниматься всем. Поверьте, есть пацаны, которые вроде и на олимпиады по информатике проходят, и при этом к математике относятся как к чему-то совершенно им не нужному - ну, надо в школе хорошую оценку иметь, но не более того... А фраза - переделка из "Контакта" В.Полищука: *«Разговаривая с профессором Бурцевым, невольно вспоминаешь, что во времена его юности наука была занятием людей интеллигентных»*.

Comment: @АндрейНиколишин "Это никогда не поздно и никому не рано" :) Поверьте, хуже от изучения математики точно не будет!

Comment: @Harry это действительно все очень грустно